# How to wait on different events simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have an open socket connection to a server.

On the one hand, in my code, I want to wait on a `BlockingQueue` for a message to be handed to me for sending to that server, then write it to the `OutputStream`.
When I send such a message, this normally expects an answer from the server (which needs to be read from the `InputStream`).

At the same time, I want to continuously listen on the socket's `InputStream` for spontaneous incoming messages from the server (server generated events).

Is there a recommended pattern for handling such a situation?
I obviously expect to have at least 2 threads involved (waiting on the two inputs - `BlockingQueue` and `Socket`). Any pointers are welcome on how to sync those, links to docs/blogs welcome.

Comment: So is the key question here how to distinguish synchronous responses to your messages from the spontaneous messages, both of which come in on the same stream? If so, more info about the protocol you are using on that stream will probably be necessary.

Comment: Sounds a little bit like IMAP

Comment: If you can tell between the responses and the events, you can simply have one queue for each. Then after sending a request, you block on the response queue.

Comment: It seems like it might be best to have a single `BlockingQueue` and then all events are added to that queue with a type and handled accordingly. ServerSideEventHandler would add events to that queue and you would just have any number of threads pulling events from that queue.